# Automatically sync git repo to Amazon S3 site

Tags: git, amazon-s3

I'm using an Amazon S3 site to host a website. I'm aiming to use a git repo to store the content and versioning and I'd like the repo to automatically update the S3 site once something is checked into the master branch. Is this possible?

Ideally I'd like to use a service such as Github or Bitbucket to host the repo. Happy to set up a VPS to run a process to manage the sync between the git repo and S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. Use puppet to periodically do a git pull of the github repo. This isn't exactly what puppet is ment for, but it is possible.
2. A simple bash script to do a git pull. You can add this to a cron job and have it run at a regular interval. This will be the simplest/quickest solution.
3. Look into alternatives such as
   pagoda box  https://pagodabox.com/features/git-php-hosting
   jenkins http://jenkins-ci.org

Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository